# How to search data efficiently with React Native ListView

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a filter and search function that would allow user to type in keyword and return result(array) and re-render the row

This is the event arrays that being passed in into the createDataSource function

[image]

The problem I am having now is my search function can't perform filter and will return the entire parent object although I specifically return the indexed object.

Here's what I got so far

```
class Search extends Component {

  state = { isRefreshing: false, searchText: '' }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.createDataSource(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.createDataSource(nextProps);
    if (nextProps) {
      this.setState({ isRefreshing: false })
    }
  }

  createDataSource({ events }) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(events);
  }

  //return arrays of event from events
  renderRow(event) {
    return <EventItem event={event} />;
  }

  onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({ isRefreshing: true });
    this.props.pullEventData()
  }

  setSearchText(event) {
   let searchText = event.nativeEvent.text;
   this.setState({ searchText })

   var eventLength = this.props.events.length
   var events = this.props.events

   const filteredEvents = this.props.events.filter(search)
   console.log(filteredEvents);

   function search() {
     for (var i = 0; i < eventLength; i++) {
       if (events[i].title === searchText) {
         console.log(events[i].title)
         return events[i];
       }
     }
   }
  }

  render() {
    const { skeleton, centerEverything, container, listViewContainer, makeItTop,
    textContainer, titleContainer, descContainer, title, desc, listContainer } = styles;

    return(
      <View style={[container, centerEverything]}>
        <TextInput
           style={styles.searchBar}
           value={this.state.searchText}
           onChange={this.setSearchText.bind(this)}
           placeholder="Search" />
        <ListView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.listViewContainer}
          enableEmptySections
          dataSource={this.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl
              refreshing={this.state.isRefreshing}
              onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
              title="Loading data..."
              progressBackgroundColor="#ffff00"
            />
          }
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

As you can see from the image above, my code requires me to type in the full query text to display the result. And it displays all the seven array objects? why's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is wrong... it should take a callback that will be the item being evaluated for filtering.. if you return true it will keep it.

```
function search(event) {
  return ~event.title.indexOf(searchText)
}
```

You could even make the inline like..

```
const filteredEvents = this.props.events.filter(event => ~event.title.indexOf(searchText))
```

For understanding my use of `~`, read [The Great Mystery of the Tilde](https://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/).

Since `filter` returns a new array, you should be able to clone your dataSource with it. If you didn't use `filter`, you would have to call `events.slice()` to return a new array. Otherwise, the ListView doesn't pickup the changes.